# How do I make it so my customers cart is emptied upon leaving the checkout page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my e-commerce store upon clicking the add to cart button you are redirected straight to the checkout page. I want to make it so when you leave the checkout page your cart is emptied. Is there a php code that can make this work?

I tried this code but its very buggy:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'clear_cart' );
function clear_cart() {
    if ( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) == get_the_ID() || wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) == get_the_ID() ) {
        return;
    }
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

Sometimes my session just ends while on the checkout page or my cart is emptied randomly.

Comment: Haven't worked in woocommerce lately, but look at the page ID's this code is checking. It's very limited(cart/checkout), and this function is clearing your cart whenever it isn't those two pages. I'd bet that's where you're getting the random empties. Not a full answer, but hopefully helps you write something/figure something out. Looks like `WC()->cart->empty_cart();` is really all you need. Figure out how to use it for your use case ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the below may help you to empty the cart. Please add in your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wdm_empty_cart', 10,  3);
function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){
  global $woocommerce;
  $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
  // Do nothing with the data and return
  return $cart_item_data;
}
```